# Construc a complete metric which coincide with the original metric on a fixed small domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

As well known,  $(\mathbb{C}^n, \omega=:\omega_{euclidean})$ is  complete  . Let $\hat{\omega}$  be a fixed  noncomplete metric  on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

**My question: C**an we construct  a complete metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$ which coincides with $\hat{\omega}$ on
$\mathbb{B}^n$?

Comment: What's $\Bbb B^n$?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path  The unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Sorry, I have reedited it.

Comment: By metric, do you mean [the concept from differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) or [the defining function of a metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))?

Comment: @JacobManaker    The concept from complex  differential geometry.  Just like the Euclidean metric $\omega:=\Sigma \sqrt{-1}d z_i\wedge d\bar{z}_i$, a positive real $(1,1)$-form.

Comment: Did you try partition of unity?

Comment: @ArcticChar  Applying the partition of unity can easily get a hermitian form which coincide with $\hat{\omega}$ on $\mathbb{B}^n$. But the completeness seems difficult to check.  If the desired hermitian form can be easily constructed, then this metric may be of the form $\omega=\lambda_1 \omega_{euclidean}+\lambda_2\hat{\omega}$, where $\lambda_1>0$  and  $\lambda_2\geq 0$. But the condition $\omega=\hat{\omega}$ on $\mathbb{B}^n$  may has no solution when $n>>1$. But if $\omega$ is not of the above form,  it seems difficult to ensure the completeness.

Comment: Partition of unity allows you to interpolate between $\hat\omega$ (on $B^n$) and $\omega$ (on the complement to the ball of radius 2). Can you finish now?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you be a little more specific? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega_0$ denote the Euclidean metric on ${\mathbb C}^n$ and $\omega$ the given (incomplete) metric. Let $B(0,R)$ denote the open ball centered at the origin, of radius $R$, with respect to the Euclidean metric. Let $\rho$ denote a smooth function on ${\mathbb C}^n$ which equals $1$ on $B(0,1)$, vanishes on the complement to $B(0,2)$ and, overall, takes values in the interval $[0,1]$. (You learn how to construct such functions when you learn about the partition of unity.)

Now, define the following:
$$
\omega':= \rho \omega + (1-\rho)\omega_0
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that $\omega'$ is indeed a metric, equal to $\omega$ on $B(0,1)$, equal $\omega_0$ on the complement to $B(0,2)$. You will also verify that $\omega'$ is complete (since it equals the complete metric $\omega_0$ outside of a compact subset.